# Bazel has no definition for py_proto_library

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, bazel

I'm getting the following error when trying to run

`$ bazel build object_detection/...`

And I'm getting ~20 of the same error (1 for each time it attempts to build that). I think it's something with the way I need to configure bazel to recognize the py_proto_library, but I don't know where, or how I would do this.

`/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow_models/object_detection/protos/BUILD:325:1: name 'py_proto_library' is not defined (did you mean 'cc_proto_library'?).`

I also think it could be an issue with the fact that initially I had installed the cpp version of tensorflow, and then I built it for python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being running this command, like the instructions say:

```
$ protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

and then running this command, like the instructions say.:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `load` in the `BUILD` file you're building?
`load("@protobuf//:protobuf.bzl", "py_proto_library")`?
The error seems to indicate the symbol `py_proto_library`  isn't loaded into skylark.

Comment: ```ERROR: package contains errors: object_detection/protos.
ERROR: error loading package 'object_detection': Extension file not found. Unable to load package for '@protobuf//:protobuf.bzl': The repository could not be resolved.
ERROR: error loading package 'object_detection': Extension file not found. Unable to load package for '@protobuf//:protobuf.bzl': The repository could not be resolved.```

Where is that supposed to be stored?

Comment: The only one that I can find is in
`~/.cache/bazel/_bazel_derek/<hex_dump>/org_tensorflow/external/protobuf/protobuf.bzl`

Comment: AFK but essentially @protobuf means you need to import the external repository called protobuf. I'll try searching later

Comment: It appears to be a combination of your answer, and the fact that, when I initially cloned tensorflow, I didn't 
`git clone --recurse-submodules  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`

Comment: Got you. For future visitors (and so I'll update my answer) what is the remote repository definition that helped you?

Comment: I don't know yet, I don't know that the problem has been fixed yet. I'm currently pulling github again with the recurse-submodules, and then I'm going to rebuild. I will let you know when I find out so you can update your answer.

Comment: This did not fix my problem, unfortunately.

Comment: I still don't know how to fix this, but I reinstalled everything from scratch and it worked.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#protobuf_pip_package_31
This was also helpful

Comment: I see. Feel free to answer your question and accept it.